# return json in this format with php

Tags: php, json

```
{
    code: "AL",
    z: 3204
}, {
    code: "DZ",
    z: 35468
},
```

trying to return something similar. I am doing this :

```
$arr = array ('code'=>array('z'),'US'=>2233332,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just follow the formatting your json:

```
$foo = array(
    array(
       'code' => 'AL',
       'z' => 3204
    ),
    array(
       'code' => 'DZ',
       'z' => 35468
   )
);
```